# Post_per_page -1 returns only half the results

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type which I created in functions.php.

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Restaurantes',
    'singular_name'      => 'Restaurante',
    'add_new'            => 'Añadir Nuevo',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Añadir Nuevo Restaurante',
    'edit_item'          => 'Editar Restaurante',
    'new_item'           => 'Nuevo Restaurante',
    'all_items'          => 'Todos los Restaurantes',
    'view_item'          => 'Ver Ver Restaurante',
    'search_items'       => 'Buscar Restaurantes',
    'not_found'          => 'No se encontraron restaurantes',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Restaurantes no encontrados en la Papelera',
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Restaurantes'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'restaurante' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  );

  register_post_type( 'restaurante', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

I am trying to display all items belonging to this custom post type in an archive page. I have 460 entries of this custom post type.  I created the file `archive-restaurante.php`

I am trying to display all results order by a custom field called `restaurante_municipio`

```
<?php 
query_posts( 
    wp_parse_args(
         $wp_query->query
        ,array('post_type' => 'restaurante',
               'posts_per_page' => -1, 
               'meta_key' => 'restaurante_municipio',
               'orderby' => 'meta_value',
               'order' => 'ASC')
    )
);
global $wp_query; 
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts; 
echo '<p><b>Restaurantes: '.$total_results.'</b>';
?>

if(have_posts() ) {     
?>
...
..
.
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
..
.
<?php endwhile; ?>
...
..
.
```

The number of displayed items is 230 the total number of results (460) divided by 2.

If I change the posts_per_page to 100, the number of results displayed is 50. Again post_per_page divided by 2.

If I change the post_per_page to 920, the number of results displayed is 230 again.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: when debuging wp_query, I always first print_r($wp_query) which contains sql query. just a little note, I bet someone here will tell you using get_posts or WP_Query rather than query_posts.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by the comments I replaced the query_posts by a WP_Query query.

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'restaurante',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'restaurante_municipio',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC');
$the_query = null;
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    $total_results = $the_query->found_posts; 
    echo '<p><b>Restaurantes: '.$total_results.'</b>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ...
        ..
        .
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now it is working